# Gradient Descent via Weight Parameter

Tags: gradient-descent, neural-networks

Let $f_{\Theta}: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a neural network such that
$$
f_{\Theta}(\mathbf{x})=W^{(2)} \sigma\left(W^{(1)} \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}^{(1)}\right)+\mathbf{b}^{(2)}
$$
where
$$
W^{(1)} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}, W^{(2)} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}, \mathbf{b}^{(1)} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}, \mathbf{b}^{(2)} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}
$$
and $\sigma$ is the ReLU function. Suppose the parameter $\Theta=\left\{W^{(1)}, W^{(2)}, \mathbf{b}^{(1)}, \mathbf{b}^{(2)}\right\}$ is initialized as
$$
W^{(1)}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right]^{\top}, W^{(2)}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -2 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right], \mathbf{b}^{(1)}=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]^{\top}, \mathbf{b}^{(2)}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]^{\top} .
$$
To minimize the $L^{2} \operatorname{loss} \ell(\Theta)=\frac{1}{2}\left\|\mathbf{y}-f_{\Theta}(\mathbf{x})\right\|^{2}$, one have to use the gradient descent method with a learning rate $\gamma=1$. How is it possible to evaluate $\Theta$ for two iterations of the optimization when we have a training data?
$$
\mathcal{D}=\left\{\left(\left[\begin{array}{ll}
2 & -3
\end{array}\right]^{\top},\left[\begin{array}{ll}
-4 & 0
\end{array}\right]^{\top}\right)\right\}
$$

In the least, if gradients could be evaluated, problem is easily manageable. However, what is the main principle for calculating the gradients w.r.t. weight parameter matrix?

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm to compute such gradient is called backpropagation. It is an instance of reverse differentiation. You have to compute $\frac{\partial l} {\partial \mathbf{W}_k}$ in a reverse manner using chain rule.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? That's true, it is backpropagation; however, the given function differs from that from normal representation, it would be great if more details according to given statements would be assisted.

Comment: ok. I do not understand what 'differs' from normal representation: can you please comment on this. It seems a very standard feedforward neural network. Also could tou show what you have done so far ?